# Alguns Problemas no modo Responsividade que não consigo solucionar

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Não estou conseguindo achar solução em alguns items quando entro no modo responsividade, e quando vou expandindo e diminuindo a tela, alguns itens saem de sua posição e fica se movendo pela tela, o que não era pra ocorrer

Tentei usar Flex ou Grid para ver se deixava mais responsivo, e alguns outros comando responsivos, porém sem resultado

Aqui a parte do código

```
HTML -

  <div class="Project-Name">
   <p  class="Ingresso">Projeto Ingresso</p>
   <p class="Info">Projeto Info</p>
   </div>
   </div>

}

CSS - 
{

.Project-Name {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  top: -9rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Inter;
  
}

.Ingresso {
  position: relative;
  left: -28.6%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 
  
  
}

.Info {
  position: relative;
  right: -5%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: -0.2rem;
 
}
```

[Problema de Responsividade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKYgk.png)

Quando eu diminuo ou expando a página esses itens param de ficar fixos

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/snmt7.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKYgk.png)

Comment: poderia incluir o css e a parte do teu html que esta tendo dificuldade ?

Comment: Adicionei o codigo acima

Comment: adicionei também uma imagem

Comment: Observando teu css e com base na sua afirmação, parece que é por conta do absoluto no momento em que a página é redimensionada, esta relativa ao topo, mas quando muda, ai sim só o elemento mantem a mesma distância em relação ao topo.

Answer (score -2):

Estive vendo seu caso e refiz seu código, utilizando "position: fixed;" nas classes que devem ficar fixas.

Notei que no HTML tem um div sem fechar isso tambḿe pode gerar distorção na apresentação, espero ter ajudado.

Segue o código:

```
<div class="Project-Name">
    <p  class="Ingresso">Projeto Ingresso</p>
    <p class="Info">Projeto Info</p>
</div>
```

```
.Project-Name {
  position: relative;
  color: #b41919;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Inter;
  
}

.Ingresso {
  left: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

.Info {

  left: 300px;
  top: -0.2rem;
  position: fixed;
 
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Os elementos `Ingresso` e o `Info` ambos foram estilizados como `relative`. Quando a tela foi redimensionada, eles foram medidos em relação ao elemento pai mais próximo que tinha uma posição definida. Como o `Project-Name` também estava como relative, eles foram medidos em relação ao elemento raiz.

Com o uso do `viewport width` e do `viewport height`, as medidas passam a ser baseadas no tamanho da tela do dispositivo, tornando-as relativas às dimensões da tela e não em relação aos elementos pai.

```
.Project-Name {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2vw /*20px ajustes*/; 
  margin: 0;
  top: -9vh /*-9rem*/;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Inter;
  
}

.Ingresso {
  position: relative;
  left: -28.6vw /*-28.6%*/;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 
  
  
}

.Info {
  position: relative;
  right: -5vw /*-5%*/;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: -0.2vh /*-0.2rem*/;
 
}
```